# if/else statements accepting strings in both capital and lower-case letters in python

Tags: python, if-statement, uppercase, lowercase, capitalize

Is there a quick way for an "if" statement to accept a string regardless of whether it's lower-case, upper-case or both in python?

I'm attempting to write a piece of code where the number "3" can be entered as well as the word "three"or "Three" or any other mixture of capital and lower-case and it will still be accepted by the "if" statement in the code. I know that I can use "or" to get it to accept "3" as well as any other string however don't know how to get it to accept the string in more than one case. So far I have:

```
if (Class == "3" or Class=="three"):
    f=open("class3.txt", "a+")
```

Comment: Use `.lower()` to normalize user-supplied value?

Comment: Or if you have plenty of if/else then I would rather suggest having a func foo which converts 3 to three...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just convert [`Class`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#classes) to lowercase using [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and test it.

```
if Class == "3" or Class.lower() == "three":
    f=open("class3.txt", "a+")
```

Of course, you can also use [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) too.

```
if Class == "3" or Class.upper() == "THREE":
    f=open("class3.txt", "a+")
```

One last thing is that you can check for `"3"` and `"three"` at the same time using `in`.

```
if Class.lower() in {"3", "three"}:
    f=open("class3.txt", "a+")
```

When using `in` for an `if` statement, you have several options. You can use a set, `{"3", "three"}`, which I used, a list, `["3", "three"]`, or a tuple, `("3", "three")`.

One last thing to note is that calling [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) or [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) on `"3"` will give you `"3"`, but calling it on the integer `3`, will throw an error, so you can't use `in` if `3` as an integer is a possibly value for [`Class`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#classes).

Comment: In your last example, you might want to consider using set instead: `{'3', 'three'}`. Not only it provides faster look up, it is the right data type for the job.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `in` operator with `list`.

```
if Class.lower() in ['3', 'three']:
```

---

Just for reference `'3'.lower()` returns string `3`.

```
>>> '3'.lower()
'3'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just force all strings to lower case and only check the lower case like this:

```
if (Class == "3" or Class.lower() == "three"):
    f=open("class3.txt", "a+")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `string.lower()` you can turn the whole string to lower case so you can check it in an if statement. Just replace string with your actual string. So `Class.lower()`

Answer (score 2):

Typically to do an insensitive compare I'll make my variable lowercase.  Though `Class` is a risky name to use because `class` is s keyword you could do the following

```
Class = Class.lower()
if(Class =="3" or Class=="three"):
```

And so forth

I'd save it as lower only if you don't need to preserve the case for anything later, and especially if you have other comparisons like against "four" as well

Comment: using lower before the if is fine but your `Class == 3` will never match as it is trying to match int 3 to string 3. Should have `Class == "3"`

Answer (score 1):

Make the string lower case.:

```
Class.lower() == "three"
```