# Python in vs ==. Which to Use in this case?

Tags: python

I am making an **AJAX** call and passing variable `pub` in it which could be `1` or `0`.

As a beginner I want to be double sure of the variable type that is coming in. I am aware I can easily convert to `int()` and the problem is actually not with AJAX result but it led to this question.

My code:

```
if pub == 1 or pub == '1':
    #execute funcA()
```

But the above is not so pythonic for me so I tried:

```
if pub in [1,'1']:
    #execute funcA()
```

Which of the above code is better in terms of:

1. Performance(speed).
2. Best practice.
3. Memory usage.

Comment: As you are making a Ajax call so it will be serialized which means it will be always `'1'`

Comment: Why have you tagged both 2.7 and 3.x?

Comment: based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values I would use pub in {1,1} or pub in (1,-1)

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277347/if-else-statements-accepting-strings-in-both-capital-and-lower-case-letters-in-p/30277407#30277407

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Performance**: in is better

```
timeit.timeit("pub='1'; pub == 1 or pub == '1'")
0.07568907737731934
timeit.timeit("pub='1'; pub in[1, '1']")
0.04272890090942383
timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub == 1 or pub == '1'")
0.07502007484436035
timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub in[1, '1']")
0.07035684585571289

#other options
timeit.timeit("pub='1'; pub in (1,'1')")
0.04643988609313965
timeit.timeit("pub='1'; pub in {1,'1'}")
0.17076611518859863
timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub in (1,'1')")
0.047419071197509766
timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub in {1,'1'}")
0.1770930290222168
```

So, `{} > or > [] > ()` based on performance.

**Practice**: `in` is preferred as it is less to type. `(), [], {}` equally good based on practice

**Memory**:

```
sys.getsizeof([1,"1"])
88
sys.getsizeof("1",1)
38

#other options
sys.getsizeof(("1",1))
72
sys.getsizeof({"1",1})
232
```

So, `{} > [] > () > or` based on memory

**Although not asked,, good to know:**

**Functionality**: Value equality and not reference equality

`in` is just sequential checking equality `==`. So similar. `in` uses `==` and  not `is`.
What I mean to say is this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,a]
>>> b
[1, [1, 2, 3]]
>>> 1 in b
True
>>> a in b
True
>>> [1,2,3] in b
True
```

So it is implemented **not** like this:

```
>>> for i in b:
...     print [1,2,3] is i
... 
False
False
```

`is` will return True if two variables point to the same object, `==` if the objects referred to by the variables are equal. **`in` uses `==`**

Comment: *"**`in` uses `==`**"* - only if `is` doesn't match anything. Also note that your `timeit` includes the cost of creating the object (e.g. set literal), which isn't necessarily representative.

Answer (score 8):

This code is better

```
if pub in [1,'1']:
    #execute funcA()
```

because it's slightly faster but mainly because it is **not redundant**. The variable `pub` appears only once there.

Comment: This is also nice because it allows you to easily add more values in the future, while keeping it readable. `if pub in [1, '1', 'one', 'uno']:`

Answer (score 3):

So performance wise `in` is better :

```
timeit.timeit("pub='1'; pub == 1 or pub == '1'")
0.16224503758795805
timeit.timeit("pub='1'; pub in[1, '1']")
0.13723585976354258
timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub == 1 or pub == '1'")
0.07986264585216674
timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub in[1, '1']")
0.07246544186018866
```

And as per memory space the `if` is better since list uses slightly more memory

```
sys.getsizeof([1,"1"])
44
sys.getsizeof(1)
12
sys.getsizeof("1")
22 
sys.getsizeof("1",1)
22
```

This is due to the fact that when even empty list is created it takes memory space

```
sys.getsizeof([])
36
```

I don't know about the `best practice aspect`

**For me  the most pythonic way would be is to use `in`** since it reduces the typing

Answer (score 1):

**1. Performance:**

```
>>> timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub == 1 or pub == '1'", number=10000)
0.0017161369323730469
>>> timeit.timeit("pub=1; pub in[1, '1']", number=10000)
0.0013611316680908203
```

**2. Best Practice:**
It's good to write programme in a pythonic way I prefer (pub in [1, '1'])

**3. Memory Usage:**
number 1 and string '1' is always cached in python, you can verify the refcount for these objects. So ideally it won't take any extra memory.

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
833
>>> sys.getrefcount('1')
16
```

If you use list that needs more memory needs to be allocated to refer these cached objects. (below is in 64 bit type)

```
>>> sys.getsizeof([1, '1'])
88
```

These 88 bytes of memory you are gonna allocate extra than the other way of doing.

I would suggest to go with :

```
if pub in [1,'1']:
    #execute funcA()
```

Answer (score 0):

In speed:
`in` is faster and by a lot.
To prove it, here is the code.

```
from datetime import datetime

start0 = datetime.now()
pub = 1
if pub == 1 or pub == '1':
    # execute funcA()
    pass
end0 = datetime.now() - start0
print end0
start1 = datetime.now()

if pub in [1, '1']:
    # execute funcA()
    pass
end1 = datetime.now() - start1
print end1
print end0 - end1
```

Output:

```
0:00:00.000045
0:00:00.000007
0:00:00.000038
```

In space:
`==` is a whole lot better.
`in` takes O(2) space while `==` takes O(1) space

According to me, the best practice is using `in` since it is a lot faster and saves a lot of typing

Answer (score 0):

Not really true. If you switch the order you would see different result, just put in order below:

```
pub = 1
if pub in [1, '1']:
    # execute funcA()
    pass
end1 = datetime.now() - start1
print end1
print end0 - end1

start0 = datetime.now()
if pub == 1 or pub == '1':
    # execute funcA()
    pass
end0 = datetime.now() - start0
print end0
start1 = datetime.now()
```